# Number of roots of $a\sin \theta+b\cos \theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta=0$ in $[0,2\pi)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can we find the number of roots of $a\sin \theta+b\cos \theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta=0$ in $[0,2\pi)$.

Taking $t=\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$, we may change the above equation into a fourth order system $f(t)=bt^4-2(a-1)t^3-2(a+1)t-b$. And find the number of roots of $f$.

Comment: suppose both $a$ and $b$ non-zero. then if $s = \tan \theta$ we have $a s^2 -s + b = 0$

Comment: The quartic has a double zero when its discriminant is zero.  That separates regions of 2 zeros from 4 or 0 zeros.